# Signature pad doesn't work when I use 2 forms

Tags: javascript, forms, signaturepad

I'm creating a contact form and I want to put a signature field. I'm using a **szimek** repository:
https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad and it works perfect on individual form, but now I need to put two contact forms with two signature fields in the same HTML and it didn't work anymore.

I have two contact form and I switch every form with radio buttons. Here the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ca">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        
        <!-- Signature libraries -->
        <script src="files/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="files/signature_pad.js"></script>
        
        
        <!-- Switching forms -->
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function displayForm(c) {
            if (c.value == "2") {    
                jQuery('#memberForm').toggle('show');
                jQuery('#requestForm').hide();
                }
            if (c.value == "1") {
                jQuery('#requestForm').toggle('show');
                jQuery('#memberForm').hide();
                }
            };
        </script>


        <!-- Initialize signature_pad -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
            var canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");
            var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
                });
            
            function resizeCanvas() {
                var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
                canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
                canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
                canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
                signaturePad.clear();
                }
            window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
            resizeCanvas();
        </script>


        <!-- Export signature as an image file -->
        <script>
        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit",function(e)
        {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var image = ctx.toDataURL(); // data:image/png....
            document.getElementById('base64').value = image;
        }
        ,false);
        </script>
        
        
        
        

    </head>

    <body>

 <!-- Special form -->   
        <form>
            <p>
                Select an option:
            </p>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input> I want to do a new program
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input> I want to register
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
        </form>
        <div style="display:none" id="requestForm">
            <form id="request" action="solicitud.php" method="POST">
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="programa" id="programa">
                Day and time - Option 1: <br>
                <input type="text" name="horari1" id="horari1">
                Day and time - Option 2: <br>
                <input type="text" name="horari2" id="horari2">
               
                <!-- Signature field -->
                <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
                <div class="description">Sign</div>
                <div class="signature-pad--body">
                    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px black solid; " id="canvas"></canvas>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- It collects the data signature field and sends it to the server-->
                <input type="hidden" name="pacient_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
                <input type="submit">

            </form>        
        </div>


        <div style="display:none" id="memberForm">
            <form id="member" action="membre.php" method="POST">
                Name and surname:
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                Adress:
                <input type="text" name="adress" id="adress">
                Email:
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                  <!-- Signature field -->
                <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
                <div class="description">Sign</div>
                <div class="signature-pad--body">
                    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px black solid; " id="canvas"></canvas>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- It collects the data signature field and sends it to the server-->
                <input type="hidden" name="pacient_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
                <input type="submit">

            </form>
        </div>
```

When I put outside the form it works perfectly, but when this is inside the form, signature field is black and I cannot draw anything:

```html
  <!-- Signature field -->
                <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
                <div class="description">Sign</div>
                <div class="signature-pad--body">
                    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px black solid; " id="canvas"></canvas>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- It collects the data signature field and sends it to the server-->
                <input type="hidden" name="pacient_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
                <input type="submit">
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is a div sytle=display:none but I don't know how can I resolve it.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have two signature pads on the same page.

Please try the following

```
<table style="width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(1)"></input> I want to do a new program
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(2)"></input> I want to register
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
            
<script>
function displayForm(var1)
{

document.getElementById("show1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("show2").style.display="none";

if (var1==1)
{document.getElementById("show1").style.display="block";}
if (var1==2)
{document.getElementById("show2").style.display="block";}


}

</script>
            
            
<div id=show1 class="sigPad" style="display:none;">
<ul class="sigNav">
<li class="drawIt"><a id="startdraw" href="#draw-it" >Start Signing</a></li>
<li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="typed"></div>
<canvas  width="600" height="160" style="border:1px solid black;" id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
</div>


<div id=show2 class="sigPad2"  style="display:none;">
<ul class="sigNav">
<li class="drawIt"><a id="startdraw" href="#draw-it" >Start Signing</a></li>
<li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="typed"></div>
<canvas  width="600" height="160" style="border:1px solid black;" id="myCanvas" ></canvas>


</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://www.createchhk.com/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad();
      $('.sigPad2').signaturePad();
      
    });
  </script>
```

Please **add other form elements (input boxes), canvas.toDataURL** to do the form submission part yourself.

You may visit `this link` to see the effect too:
http://www.createchhk.com/so_29dec.html

Comment: Sure, but I can't understand why doesn't work when I put every signature pad under <div style="display:none". I follow this code (is very similar than yours): http://jsfiddle.net/szimek/ps65Q/ and it works fine but not inside display:none. How can we resolve this? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: So you mean if you add display:none it will cause the signature pad(s) to be non-functional ? Let me try

Comment: Hi I have revised my answer so that it will show the effect when you have the display:none (it works). Please see my revised answer.

Comment: HI, just follow-up, did my answer solve your problem ?

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much!! Works perfect. Now I know how to do it if happens again in the future. Have a happy new Year